# Advanced proportion calculation in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, math

I am attempting to determine the proportion of DD (`branch`) in relation to AA, BB, CC where DD exists in the subset of employee, account, fruit. Each employee's `pcnt` adds to 1 (100%).

Breaking it down, this calculation must satisfy the following conditions:

- Ignore subsets (employee, account, fruit) without DD

```
| EMPLOYEE | ACCOUNT |      FRUIT | BRANCH | PCNT |
---------------------------------------------------
|      123 |  Fruit1 |      Apple |     AA |  0.1 |
```

- Ignore subsets (employee, account, fruit) that are entirely DD

```
| EMPLOYEE | ACCOUNT |      FRUIT | BRANCH | PCNT |
---------------------------------------------------
|      123 |  Fruit2 |      Apple |     DD | 0.05 |
```

- Proportionally distribute DD over AA, BB, CC within subsets (employee, account, fruit)

From:

```
| EMPLOYEE | ACCOUNT |      FRUIT | BRANCH | PCNT |
---------------------------------------------------
|      123 |  Fruit1 | Strawberry |     AA | 0.05 |
|      123 |  Fruit1 | Strawberry |     BB | 0.02 |
|      123 |  Fruit1 | Strawberry |     CC | 0.07 |
|      123 |  Fruit1 | Strawberry |     DD | 0.10 |
```

Into:

```
| EMPLOYEE | ACCOUNT |      FRUIT | BRANCH | PCNT |
---------------------------------------------------
|      123 |  Fruit1 | Strawberry |     AA | 0.09 |
|      123 |  Fruit1 | Strawberry |     BB | 0.03 |
|      123 |  Fruit1 | Strawberry |     CC | 0.12 |
```

The calculations for the subset proportions above would be:

```
AA + {AA * [DD / (AA + BB + CC)]}

0.05 + {0.05 * [0.1 / (0.05 + 0.02 + 0.07)]} = 0.09
0.02 + {0.02 * [0.1 / (0.05 + 0.02 + 0.07)]} = 0.03
0.07 + {0.07 * [0.1 / (0.05 + 0.02 + 0.07)]} = 0.12
```

- After these calculations and conditions, the sum of `pcnt` should be 1
- There may be some subsets where not all three (AA, BB, CC) are present

**Table Structure**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  employee tinyint NOT NULL,
  account varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  fruit varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  branch char(2) NOT NULL,
  pcnt decimal(3,2) NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (employee, account, fruit, branch))
```

**Sample Data**

```
INSERT INTO tbl (employee, account, fruit, branch, pcnt) VALUES 
(123, 'Fruit1', 'Apple', 'AA', '0.1'),
(123, 'Fruit1', 'Mango', 'DD', '0.02'),
(123, 'Fruit1', 'Mango', 'CC', '0.1'),
(123, 'Fruit1', 'Mango', 'BB', '0.02'),
(123, 'Fruit1', 'Mango', 'AA', '0.06'),
(123, 'Fruit1', 'Pineapple', 'DD', '0.01'),
(123, 'Fruit1', 'Pineapple', 'CC', '0.05'),
(123, 'Fruit1', 'Pineapple', 'BB', '0.05'),
(123, 'Fruit1', 'Pineapple', 'AA', '0.05'),
(123, 'Fruit1', 'Strawberry', 'DD', '0.10'),
(123, 'Fruit1', 'Strawberry', 'CC', '0.07'),
(123, 'Fruit1', 'Strawberry', 'BB', '0.02'),
(123, 'Fruit1', 'Strawberry', 'AA', '0.05'),
(123, 'Fruit2', 'Apple', 'DD', '0.05'),
(123, 'Fruit2', 'Mango', 'DD', '0.01'),
(123, 'Fruit2', 'Mango', 'CC', '0.02'),
(123, 'Fruit2', 'Mango', 'BB', '0.01'),
(123, 'Fruit2', 'Mango', 'AA', '0.01'),
(123, 'Fruit2', 'Pineapple', 'DD', '0.02'),
(123, 'Fruit2', 'Pineapple', 'CC', '0.03'),
(123, 'Fruit2', 'Pineapple', 'BB', '0.02'),
(123, 'Fruit2', 'Pineapple', 'AA', '0.02'),
(123, 'Fruit2', 'Strawberry', 'DD', '0.01'),
(123, 'Fruit2', 'Strawberry', 'CC', '0.05'),
(123, 'Fruit2', 'Strawberry', 'AA', '0.05')
```

**What I've tried**

```
SELECT b.*, 
    CASE WHEN (b.Sum_AA + b.Sum_BB + b.Sum_CC) > 0 THEN 'hello'
    ELSE NULL
    END
FROM (
    SELECT a.*, 
        (SELECT SUM(pcnt) AS [pcnt] FROM dbo.tbl
            WHERE employee = a.employee AND account = a.account AND fruit = a.fruit
            AND branch = 'AA') AS [Sum_AA],
        (SELECT SUM(pcnt) AS [pcnt] FROM dbo.tbl
            WHERE employee = a.employee AND account = a.account AND fruit = a.fruit
            AND branch = 'BB') AS [Sum_BB],
        (SELECT SUM(pcnt) AS [pcnt] FROM dbo.tbl
            WHERE employee = a.employee AND account = a.account AND fruit = a.fruit
            AND branch = 'CC') AS [Sum_CC]
    FROM (
        SELECT employee, account, fruit, SUM(pcnt) AS [Sum_DD]
        FROM dbo.tbl
        WHERE employee = 123 AND branch = 'DD'
        GROUP BY employee, account, fruit) a) b
```

Up to the query above, I've grouped AA, BB, CC. However, I have no idea how to proceed. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you need, try this.

```
WITH ct1 AS
(        
    SELECT employee, account, fruit
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN branch = 'AA' THEN pcnt ELSE 0 END) AS AA    
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN branch = 'BB' THEN pcnt ELSE 0 END) AS BB    
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN branch = 'CC' THEN pcnt ELSE 0 END) AS CC
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN branch = 'DD' THEN pcnt ELSE 0 END) AS DD
    FROM tbl 
    GROUP BY  employee, account, fruit having SUM(CASE WHEN branch = 'DD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1       
)
SELECT t.*
    ,new_pcnt = t.pcnt + ROUND((t.pcnt * ( DD /(AA + BB + CC))),2)
FROM tbl t
INNER JOIN ct1 
  ON t.employee = ct1.employee
  AND t.account = ct1.account
  AND t.fruit = ct1.fruit
WHERE t.branch <> 'DD'
```

Comment: I think you did it. Thank you.